# Appengine rdbms failing when connecting to google cloud sql

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

We use google cloud sql from appengine and have been getting the following error quite frequently from our backend instance.

```
 File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app-prod/140-backend.363823736662468595/users/reports/__init__.py", line 360, in get_document_types
  cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT document_type FROM receipt WHERE ho_key=%s AND document_type IS NOT NULL', (str(ho.key())))
File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms.py", line 499, in execute
  self._DoExec(request)
File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms.py", line 375, in _DoExec
  response = self._conn.MakeRequest('Exec', request)
File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms.py", line 873, in MakeRequest
  response = self._MakeRetriableRequest(stub_method, request)
File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms.py", line 897, in _MakeRetriableRequest
  response = self.MakeRequestImpl(stub_method, request)
File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms_apiproxy.py", line 68, in MakeRequestImpl
  raise OperationalError('could not connect: ' + str(e))
```

OperationalError: could not connect: ApplicationError: 1002

Does anyone else have experience with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This error and stacktrace indicate you are using the google.appengine.api.rdbms interface that is old and deprecated.

You should replace this with the MySQLdb module which is documented as the best way to [connect to Cloud SQL from App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/) in Python. Because both interfaces comply with [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) it should be a drop in replacement. As described at the link above on GAE you will want to use create the connection with `MySQLdb.connect(unix_socket="/cloudsql/project:instance", ...)`.